# How to update items of SilverGrid or SilverList in flutter? Is there anything equivalent to notifyDatasetChanged() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, notifydatasetchanged, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

Using [the sample code provided by Emily Fortuna in a Medium article, "Slivers, Demystified"](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f), I created a Flutter list using the **SilverList** and **SilverGrid** classes. But I unable to change the data after the list is created.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Collapsing List Demo')),
        body: CollapsingList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context,
      double shrinkOffset,
      bool overlapsContent)
  {
    return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
class CollapsingList extends StatelessWidget {
  SliverPersistentHeader makeHeader(String headerText) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 60.0,
        maxHeight: 200.0,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue, child: Center(child:
        Text(headerText))),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        makeHeader('Header Section 1'),
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
          ],
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 2'),
        SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 150.0,
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Container(color: Colors.red),
              Container(color: Colors.purple),
              Container(color: Colors.green),
              Container(color: Colors.orange),
              Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 3'),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            childAspectRatio: 4.0,
          ),
          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: new Text('grid item $index'),
              );
            },
            childCount: 20,
          ),
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 4'),
        // Yes, this could also be a SliverFixedExtentList. Writing 
        // this way just for an example of SliverList construction.
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
              Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
              Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
              Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is because you extracted it out to show it here as an example but as it is right now everything inside `CollapsingList` is fixed - like there is no variable which could change so the content can change as well. Basically there are a lot of different approaches to achieve the maintaining of changing data and the change of the UI accordingly (State Management solutions).

The most basic approach in the flutter environment to update the UI is the built in `setState((){})` method of `StatefulWidgets`. So as an example you could make your `CollapsingList` a `StatefulWidget` set some variables which should change after any interaction (like clicking a button) and call `setState((){})` so the `StatefulWidget` in this case your `CollapsingList` will rebuild and the new value of the variable will be displayed / used.

Comment: This might be because you are running the App in debug mode? Or even on a Simulator on your PC? Usually `setState((){})` works pretty smoothly as long as the `StatefulWidget` is not too big